# Workflow field update (date field)

Tags: workflow, field-update

On a Agreement object I have End Date(date-data type) field , Auto Renew(checkbox), Terms months(number-data type). End date should be updated based on Term month field when Auto Renew is checked.

For ex: End date:07/07/2020 and Term months :2 when I checked the Auto Renew field, End date should be 07/09/2020.

How can we achieve this using Workflows?

In Workflow condition I selected Formula evaluates to true and specified the condition i.e Auto Renew=True. But I stuck on what to specify in Action section to achieve my scenario. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question, [Workflow for update a data field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311953/workflow-for-update-a-data-field). It was closed because you didn't provide enough detail about what you had tried, what research you did, and where you are stuck. Repeating questions without making suggested changes is a quick way to get a lot of negative attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a field update and You can add a field value of a number type  to a given date by specifying the field using ADDMONTHS function in formula:-

```
End_Date__c = ADDMONTHS( End_Date_c,  Term_month___c)
```

[image]

Read more here:- https://getawayposts.com/add-months-date-salesforce-formula-addmonths-function

Comment: We have one more field on Agreement, i.e # of terms(Number field)
If End date=14/07/2020 ,Contract Term Month= 12, no of terms=3, the end Date should be 14/07/2021 when Auto Renew is checked. and on 14/07/2021 agreement should get auto renewed and end date should be  14/07/2022, on 14/07/2022 agreement should get auto renewed and end date should be 14/07/2023 and so on based on no of Terms value.

No of Terms is for how many times it should get auto Renewed and based on end date field should be auto updated.